# FooTable unhandled error with hidden table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, footable

I am attempting to do a simple `.toggle()` using a button to show/hide specific rows in a table. I am also using [FooTable 3.0.10](https://github.com/fooplugins/FooTable/releases/tag/3.0.10), but when I have any rows with `style="display:none;"`, the table drawing fails and I get the following error:

> FooTable: unhandled error thrown during a draw operation. TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined

Here is an example of the code:

```js
$("#toggle-zero-balances").on("click", function() {
  $(".zero-bal-row").toggle('fast');
});
$('.my-table').footable();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/3.0.10/footable.js"></script>

<button id="toggle-zero-balances">Show zero balances</button>

<table class="table my-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-breakpoints="">Balances 1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr class="zero-bal-row" style="display: none;">
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please advise if there are any workarounds/solutions to this.

Comment: We can't help if we can't reproduce :) Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've updated the question. Hopefully there is enough info there to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Footable needs <tbody> to works properly, so, your table should looks liek this: 
```
<table class="table my-table"><thead>...</thead><tbody>...</tbody></table>
```

Comment: It works tho https://jsfiddle.net/rjwbe21v/, I can't seem to get the error you're getting

Comment: Use jQuery 2.20 and FooTable 3.0.10. I guess it's a bug with the FooTable version.

Comment: @DanielH. I suppose, you should probably upgrade your jQuery version